# Render HTML from Vue application's container element

Tags: html, vue.js

I have an HTML page with a Vue application, comprising a single component.

The application is mounted on an element with id `paid-content`.

*index.html*

```html
<div id="paid-content">
  <h2>You should see this if you're logged in</h2>
</div>
```

*main.ts*

```js
import PaidContent from './PaidContent.vue'
createApp(PaidContent).mount('#paid-content')
```

The component itself checks if the user is logged in.

*PaidContent.vue*

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
    methods: {
        getUser() {
            return "bob"
        },
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <template v-if="getUser() !== null">
        You are signed in!
        <slot></slot>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        Please sign in.
    </template>
</template>
```

Right now it shows:

> *You are signed in!*.

I would like it to render the HTML inside the `paid-content` container to show:

> You are signed in!
>
> ### You should see this if you're logged in

By default it seems that Vue removes the `<h2>` element.

What I've tried:

- using a slot
- *In-DOM Root Component Template* as per [the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app). This syntax is not compatible with the static site generator I'm using (Hugo).

Is there a way to render the HTML from the container element within the Vue component?

(Vue version is `3.3.2`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get the root div aka `#paid-content`'s `innerHTML`
- Pass it down to `PaidContent` as a prop
- Render it using `v-html`

### `PaidContent.vue`

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: {
    // here
    paidContentHtml: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getUser() {
      return "bob";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <template v-if="getUser() !== null">
    You are signed in!

    <!-- Render it here -->
    <div v-html="paidContentHtml"></div> 
  </template>
  <template v-else> Please sign in. </template>
</template>
```

### `main.ts`

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import PaidContent from "./PaidContent.vue";

const $paidContent = document.querySelector("#paid-content")?.innerHTML;

createApp(PaidContent, {
  paidContentHtml: $paidContent,
}).mount("#paid-content");
```